# Homebrew Logstash failed to open a file under ~/Documents

Tags: macos, logstash

I installed the Logstash via Homebrew and configured the Logstash to tail a log file under my `~/Documents` folder. However, the Logstash log indicate it failed to open the file with the following error.

```
[2020-09-14T13:58:27,892][WARN ][filewatch.tailmode.handlers.createinitial][others][7b0d387b8f4792cb946034cfce3f23950334ccb21b9d8b1792d718ecbf4d5c3a] failed to open /Users/xxx/Documents/project/logs/all: #<IOError: Operation not permitted>, ["org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1234:in `sysopen'", "org/jruby/RubyFile.java:365:in `initialize'", "org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1156:in `open'"]
```

I tried to add following file into the list of `Security & Privary -> Full Disk Access` but still failed.

- /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
- /usr/local/Cellar/logstash/7.9.1/bin/logstash
- /usr/local/Cellar/logstash/7.9.1/bin/logstash-plugin
- /usr/local/Cellar/logstash/7.9.1/libexec/bin/logstash

I confirmed the Logstash can access other files (e.g. `/var/log/system.log`)

Here is my Logstash's input configuration.

```
input {
  file {
    path => [
      "/Users/xxx/Documents/project/logs/all"
    ]
    mode => "tail"
  }
}
```

Does anyone know why may be the cause of this failure?

Comment: Which user was executing the process?

`ps aux | grep logstash`

It may just be a file permissions issue.

Comment: I also checked that as well. the file owner and the user who executed the process are the same. The file access also has read permission for all users. rw-r--r--